# find numbers starting certain number with python

Tags: python, regex

i need to find years of dates of births only starting with `18xx` and `19xx`from string

i'm using regex to solve task

i have testing `testbirtdays = 'ABCDEFG 01.19.1701 1801 02.18.1901 2001'`

```
def getNumbers(str): 
    array = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str) 
    return array
```

i can use this function but output will be:

`getNumbers(testbirtdays)`

`#['01', '19', '1701', '1801', '02', '18', '1901', '2001']`

my function can't do 2 things:

1. i need numbers only starting wtih `18` and `19`
2. i need only `4x` numbers to get only years and ignore months/days

so i need output like:

`#['1801','1901']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way :

```
import re

re.findall(r'\b18\d{2}\b|\b19\d{2}\b', testbirtdays)
```

output:

```
['1801', '1901']
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
r'(?<![0-9])1[89][0-9]{2}(?![0-9])'
```

Or, with word boundaries:

```
r'\b1[89][0-9]{2}\b'
```

See the **[regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/mH4ZLr/2)** and **[regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/mH4ZLr/3)**.

Regex details:

- `(?<![0-9])` - no ASCII digit allowed immediately on the left
- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `1` - a `1` digit
- `[89]` -  `8` or `9`
- `[0-9]{2}` - two ASCII digit
- `(?![0-9])` - no ASCII digit allowed immediately on the right or
- `\b`  - a word boundary

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DkNalO):

```
import re

def getNumbers(s): 
    return re.findall(r'(?<![0-9])1[89][0-9]{2}(?![0-9])', s) 

testbirtdays = 'ABCDEFG 01.19.1701 1801 02.18.1901 2001'
print(getNumbers(testbirtdays)) # => ['1801', '1901']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a more specific regex like `1[8-9][0-9]{2}` : a `1`, then one of `89` then 2 digits

You can also do `(?:18|19)[0-9]{2}` start with `18`or `19` then 2 other digits

```
def getNumbers(value):
    return re.findall(r'1[8-9][0-9]{2}', value)

r = getNumbers('ABCDEFG 01.19.1701 1801 02.18.1901 2001')
print(r)  # ['1801', '1901']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_years(str):
    return re.findall(r"((?:18|19)\d{2})\b", str)

print(get_years(testbirtdays))
```

Output:

```
['1801', '1901']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test = 'ABCDEFG 01.19.1701 1801 02.18.1901 2001'
pattern = r'1[89]\d{2}'    
re.findall(pattern, test)
```

The pattern looks for 1 followed by 8 or 9, and 2 more digits.

Output:

`['1801', '1901']`

Comment: The `|` in the character class `[]` does not mean `OR` but a pipe char

Comment: But this is the output I got : `['1801', '1901']`

Comment: You get that output, but it might also match `1|01`

Comment: Ah, right. Now I get it - `[]` by itself does the `OR` part, so it should just be `[89]`.

Comment: Exactly, but now you will still get partial matches in for example 55180155 which I don't think is the desired result. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987346/5424988) provided by Wiktor Stribiżew shows how that can be prevented.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't check ahead and behind.